# correlation analysis of two signal in matlab

Tags: signals, signal-processing, sampling

let us consider following code

```
>> load relatedsig.mat;
>> [C1,lag1] = xcorr(T1,S);
[C2,lag2] = xcorr(T2,S);

figure
ax(1) = subplot(211);
plot(lag1/Fs,C1,'k');
ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on
title('Cross-correlation between Template 1 and Signal')
ax(2) = subplot(212);
plot(lag2/Fs,C2,'r');
ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on
title('Cross-correlation between Template 2 and Signal')
xlabel('Time(secs)');
axis(ax(1:2),[-1.5 1.5 -700 700 ])
>>
```

i have question related to this part - `plot(lag1/Fs,C1,'k');`

**why we are dividing lags by sampling frequencies?** thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fs` say to you how many sample per second your signal was recorded !

So when you divide your lag by sampling frequencies, you just was converting the lag position in seconds.

it tells you how many seconds of delay was returned by correlation!

Comment: in other word? to  express it in simple  way

Comment: exactly, you can test for yourself, correlate two signals with for example one second lag the other and see the result in seconds `lagfromcorrelation/Fs`

Comment: no i mean how can we transform your  answer in different way, so it means after how many second is two  signal correlated?

Comment: `lag1/Fs` just convert all lags from correlation in a representation in seconds, if you want know after how many second the two signal is correlated you need find the absolute max position from the correlation `C1` see your plot and search by the peak!